# Error on executing lrzsz for sending file through minicom

Tags: serial-port, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, beagleboard, zmodem

I want to send small object code to Ezsdk 6.0 Beagleboard through serial port using minicom. I found lrzsz (http://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html) and cross compiled with  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.
I got lrb,lrx, lrz, lsb, lsx, lsz.   But on executing this on on board ,it shows

```
`root@beagleboard:/usr/bin# ./lrz
-sh: ./lrz: cannot execute binary file `
```

file properties

```
shihab@shihab:/usr/local/bin$ file lrz
lrz: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0xcf9ce9b23b5a68d2ef6ea3fa695bfe5f7e79d1a5, not stripped
```

Please  help me to port lrzsz to ezsdk 6.0

Thanks

Comment: can u share what shared library its using ? try ldd ./lrz in your target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with cross compilation

Cross compiled with

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  ./configure --target=arm-linux
```

Transferred lrz and lsz files to board
created symbolic links rz to lrz and sz to lsz

Now can send files by Ctrl A Z   via minicom..